# Insert stats in database from html page

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have made some statistics which I want to insert into database to see traffic stats.
I mostly have HTML pages so I used POST method to get statistics posted by a PHP file, but it is not working no stats are inserted into database table.

HTML Codes

```
    <form action="_global/stats/stats.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="stats" value="true" />
    </form>
```

PHP Codes

```
        if (isset($_POST['stats']))
    {
    $stats = $_POST['stats'];
    }
    else
    {$stats="false";}

    if ($stats == "true"){ 

        if(!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        }else{$url = "";}

        if(!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])){
        $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }else{$user_ip = "";}

        if(!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'])){
        $user_port = $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];
        }else{$user_port = "";}

        if(!empty($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'])){
        $server_ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
        }else{$server_ip = "";}

        if(!empty($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'])){
        $server_port = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
        }else{$server_port = "";}

        if(!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])){
        $request_type = mysql_real_escape_string ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
        }else{$request_type = "";}

        if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
        $browser_type =  mysql_real_escape_string ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        }else{$browser_type = "";} 

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO jinendra_statistics.statistics SET url='$url', user_ip='$user_ip', user_port='$user_port', server_ip='$server_ip', server_port='$server_port', request_type='$request_type', browser_type='$browser_type' ");

    }
```

Please See what's going wrong here and suggest any possible way to do it.

**Update**

PHP file with these codes is working i get values in database. but using it with HTML doesn't insert values in database.

```
        if(!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }else{$url = "";}

    if(!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])){
    $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }else{$user_ip = "";}

    if(!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'])){
    $user_port = $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];
    }else{$user_port = "";}

    if(!empty($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'])){
    $server_ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
    }else{$server_ip = "";}

    if(!empty($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'])){
    $server_port = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
    }else{$server_port = "";}

    if(!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])){
    $request_type = mysql_real_escape_string ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
    }else{$request_type = "";}

    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
    $browser_type =  mysql_real_escape_string ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    }else{$browser_type = "";} 

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO jinendra_statistics.statistics SET url='$url', user_ip='$user_ip', user_port='$user_port', server_ip='$server_ip', server_port='$server_port', request_type='$request_type', browser_type='$browser_type' ");
```

Comment: try mysql_error() to see if there is a problem in your SQL syntax.

Comment: does it generates an error? what was it?

Comment: no problem in mysql i have checked already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone reading this: There were two issues that were fixed.

1) The query had incorrect syntax, and

2) The process of submitting the form was also incorrect.

---

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO jinendra_statistics.statistics (url, user_ip, user_port, server_ip, server_port, request_type, browser_type) VALUES ('$url', '$user_ip', '$user_port', '$server_ip', '$server_port', '$request_type', '$browser_type')";
```

You want to use `SET` for `UPDATE` and the syntax I provided for `INSERT`.

---

**this/page.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['stats'])){

 if(!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}else{$url = "";}

if(!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])){
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}else{$user_ip = "";}

if(!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'])){
$user_port = $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];
}else{$user_port = "";}

if(!empty($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'])){
$server_ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
}else{$server_ip = "";}

if(!empty($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'])){
$server_port = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
}else{$server_port = "";}

if(!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])){
$request_type = mysql_real_escape_string ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
}else{$request_type = "";}

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
$browser_type =  mysql_real_escape_string ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
}else{$browser_type = "";} 

mysql_query("INSERT INTO jinendra_statistics.statistics SET url='$url', user_ip='$user_ip', user_port='$user_port', server_ip='$server_ip', server_port='$server_port', request_type='$request_type', browser_type='$browser_type' ");

if(mysql_affected_rows()){
    // it worked, redirect, confirm, etc
}
else{
    // it failed
}

}

?>


<form action="this/page.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="stats" value="true" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit Stats" />
</form>
```

Try this out. Enter the name of the file you save this as in the action.

Comment: there is no error, if i remove all if loops and run the php file, all stats gets inserted into database. but if i run it through html file nothing happns

Comment: its showing `Call to undefined function num_rows_affected()`, also i want the form to be submitted by HTML file not in php file

Comment: Now its showing `mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in`

Comment: I accidentally provided you with an incorrect function. Replace `mysql_num_rows()` with `mysql_affected_rows()` (do NOT put $result in the parentheses), and remove the `$result = ` in front of the query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15249/discussion-between-zdhickman-and-tall-boy)

Answer (score 2):

You are using half `INSERT` half `UPDATE` query.
Your query should be

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO jinendra_statistics.statistics (url, user_ip, user_port, server_ip, server_port, request_type, browser_type) VALUES ('$url', '$user_ip', '$user_port', '$server_ip', '$server_port', '$request_type', '$browser_type')";
```

Check the syntax

- [MYSQL INSERT SYNTAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html)
- [MYSQL UPDATE SYNTAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Comment: @TallboY you sure about that?

Comment: These are the only [INSERT SYNTAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html "Click Here")

Comment: I tried with zdhickman and Muhammad Zeeshan query, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is prone to [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/). Can you try using **[PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** instead?

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO jinendra_statistics.statistics (url, user_ip, 
                                   user_port, server_ip, server_port, 
                                   request_type, browser_type) 
                       VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$stmt->bindParam(1, $url);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $user_ip);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $user_port);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $server_ip);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $server_port);
$stmt->bindParam(6, $request_type);
$stmt->bindParam(7, $browser_type);

$stmt->execute();

?>
```